# Telegram Bot C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, visual-studio

У меня есть простой телеграм бот на C#, только он работает если добавить его в группу или писать ему в личные сообщения. Мне же надо, чтобы он работал в телеграм канале, а именно нужно, чтобы он мог отправлять там картинки, текст, получать контент который содержиться в этом канале

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Types;

namespace Neirodemotivator;

public class Program
{
    private static string _token = "";
    public static TelegramBotClient _botClient;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _botClient = new TelegramBotClient(_token);
        _botClient.StartReceiving(Update, Error);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    async static Task Update(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (update.Message != null)
        {
            var message = update.Message;
            if (message.Text != null)
            {
                if (message.Text.ToLower().Contains("прив"))
                {
                    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "111");
                    return;
                }
                if (message.Text.ToLower().Contains("ку"))
                {
                    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "ни");
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (message.Photo != null)
            {
                await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "111");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    private static Task Error(ITelegramBotClient arg1, Exception arg2, CancellationToken arg3)
    { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

Comment: Проблема-то конкретно в чём? Сомневаюсь, что здесь Вам кто-то бота полностью напишет...

Comment: вопрос в том, что работает ли он вообще в телеграм каналах?

Comment: Нужно добавить бота в канал и дать ему доступ к сообщениям.